# mysql replace table data from another table when condition is met

Tags: mysql

I am working on the database for a Wordpress Multisite install and need to copy multiple fields (but not all) from one table into another table, replace existing content and/or add row if they don't exist.

There are similar answers elsewhere but I can't seem to figure this out.

tables are sourcetable and targettable

columns are  option_name and option_value

basically, if option_name `field = condition1` is present in targettable copy option_value field from sourcetable and replace targettable option_value field, if not present then add it

would like to update/replace multiple fields with one query

```
REPLACE or UPDATE option_value_field in targettable with data 
from sourcetable value_field 
where name_field equals "condition1"

REPLACE or UPDATE option_value_field in targettable with data 
from sourcetable value_field 
where name_field equals "condition2"

REPLACE or UPDATE option_value_field in targettable with data 
from sourcetable value_field
where name_field equals "condition3" (add if does not exist)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make option_name field unique, and use [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement to insert/replace values in `targettable` -

```
INSERT INTO targettable
SELECT * FROM sourcetable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option_value = VALUES(option_value)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks @Devart for reply, but I'm not sure I understand how to get this to work.

When you say "make option_name field unique" -- how does that work? and is that where/how I would assign the conditions?  

I don't want to replace all fields, only a few with options_name = "condition value" and if the target table doesn't have that value, add it.